# popExit animation is not working

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I'm pretty new in android developing.

I have a simple activity with a button, and a `FrameLayout` preserve for my fragment. when pressing the button it is setting my fragment with a custom animation in the `FrameLayout`.

The animation for the entering is working well. fade in like expected.
but when i'm pressing the back button the animation is not working at all. the i see my activity in one shot.

**card_in.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="1.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:duration="2000" />

</set>
```

**card_out.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:duration="2000" />

</set>
```

**in the click event in the activity**

```
getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_in, R.animator.card_out, R.animator.card_in, R.animator.card_out)
        .replace(R.id.frgContainer, new MyFragment())
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

Is the animation works only between fragments ? if so, is there a way to do what i want ?